# Really weird, debug of the program works OK but when i run it i get a weird result

Tags: c

i'm trying to create a 'game' in C programming which throws 2 dices for the user, throws 2 dices for the PC, and whoever gets the bigger sum wins,
when i debug it in visual studio i see good results both in the variable values and the console window, but when i run it without debugging the user and the PC both always get the same value for their dices (user gets 2 and 2, and PC gets 2 and 2, for example).

Can anyone solve it? i looked at it for the last 3 hours and i just can't find what's the problem.

```
            #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
            #include <stdlib.h>
            #include <stdio.h>
            #include <time.h>
            int throwDice();
            int diceSum();
            int main()
            {
                int res1;
                res1=diceSum();
                if(res1==0)
                    printf("It is a tie!\n");
                if(res1==1)
                    printf("You Won!\n");
                if(res1==-1)
                    printf("You Lost\n");
            }
            int throwDice()
            {
            int i;
            srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
            i = (rand()%(6-1)) + 1;
            return i;
            }
            int diceSum()
            {
                int j,a=0,b,c=0,d=0;
                int array[4];
                for(j=1;j<=2;j++)
                {
                    array[c]=throwDice();
                    a=a+array[c];
                    c++;
                }
                    for(b=1;b<=2;b++)
                {
                    array[c]=throwDice();
                    d=d+array[c];
                    c++;
                }
                printf("You got %d and %d.\nYour opponent got %d and %d.\n",array[0],array[1],array[2],array[3]);
                if(a==d)
                    return 0;
                if(a>d)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return -1;
            }
```

Comment: You should seed the random numbers generator only once, not every time you throw dices. Move the call to `srand` out of the `throwDice` to `main`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everytime you call `throwDice`, you are re-initializing your random number generator with the current time.

The accuracy of time is only 1-second, so in a single run of this program, the time doesn't change, so you get the same results.

You are *supposed* to call `srand` **ONLY ONCE**, near the start of your program.

From the [**documentation**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/)

*"Two different initializations with the same seed will generate the same succession of results in subsequent calls to rand."*

Answer (score 1):

The random number generator doesn't just pull random numbers out of nowhere. When you seed it you're giving it a good number to start with, and from there it can generate a bunch of random numbers.

The problem is, it will give you a sequence of random numbers, but that sequence will be the same if you give it the same seed twice in a row. That's why it's important that the value you seed it with is relatively random. And hey, the time is pretty random, what are the chances two people will end up running the program at exactly the same time?

What you're doing, is seeding the generator before every call to `rand`, instead of seeding it at the beginning and letting the random number generator do its job. Since `time` only returns the time in seconds (see [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time)), you'll get the same number every time the loop runs until the start of the next second.